# Logical thinking for a Calculation of Square root

Tags: python, python-3.3, square-root

I've been trying to decipher this problem for the last hour right now and having some trouble here. This is the problem

> This method for calculating the square root of a number n starts by
> making a (non zero) guess at the square root. It then uses the
> original guess to calculate a new guess, according to the formula
>
> ```
> newGuess = ((n / oldGuess) + oldGuess) / 2.0;
> ```
>
> Have two variables `oldGuess` and `newGuess`. Initialize `oldGuess` to
> `n / 2.0` and calculate `newGuess` according to the above formula. Use
> a while loop to iterate as long as the absolute value of the
> difference between the `oldGuess` and `newGuess` is greater than
> `1.0E-06`. Do not forget to reset the value of `oldGuess` to the
> `newGuess` value in the while loop.
>
> In your program you will prompt the user to enter a positive number.
> If the number is negative, print an error message and ask the user to
> try again. For a positive number, calculate the square root using the
> above method. Find the difference between the square root you obtained
> and the value obtained from using the exponentiation operator. Write
> out the value the user entered, the square root you computed, and the
> difference (your square root - `n ** 0.5`)

This is my program so far

```
def main():
    n = eval(input("Enter a positive number: "))
    while (n <= 0):
        print ("Error please re-input")
        n = eval(input("Enter a positive number: "))
     
    oldGuess = n / 2.0
    newGuess = ((n / oldGuess) + oldGuess) / 2.0;
    difference = n - n ** 0.5      
    while (difference < 1 * 10 ** -6):
        print ("Error")
        difference = abs(n - n ** 0.5)
    print ("Difference:", difference)

main()
```

So I don't really understand how we can tell the program to make a guess and then calculate the square root of variable n. I don't even think my while statements are right in this context. I don't use the already embedded function the squareroot built into python so it has to be done manually I believe still lost on what it means by the guess function.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: You want to continue iterating while the absolute difference is *greater* than a small amount, not less.

Comment: Using `eval` is dangerous. Use `float` instead

Comment: You'll need to move the `newGuess` calculation into the `while` loop. You probably need `oldGuess = newGuess` somewhere too

Comment: If you're trying to implement a square root algorithm, that `n ** 0.5` really doesn't belong here.

Comment: Guessing a root is easy. It doesn't have to be a good guess; you just need to start somewhere. You could guess `1` every time without a problem.

Comment: Yeah this is a homework question I am having trouble with. Okay so what does oldGuess = newGuess actually do? I mean should that go in the while loop and the difference then continues to iterate?

Comment: `oldGuess` and `newGuess` are variables, abstract things that refer to objects. They can be set to refer to new objects throughout the course of the program; `oldGuess = newGuess` makes `oldGuess` refer to what `newGuess` currently refers to. Thus, `oldGuess = newGuess` updates your old guess to your new, better guess, so you can use it to compute a newer, better guess.

Comment: @SulimanSharif `oldGuess = newGuess` assigns the value of `newGuess` to the variable `oldGuess`. (That's technically wrong, but, just go with it.)

Comment: If you're not sure what your loops are doing, either add `print` calls that show you, or use an [interactive visualizer](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#), the built-in debugger, your favorite IDE's graphical wrapper around the debugger, etc. and find out. It's a lot easier than guessing or trying to reason it out.

Comment: Well, actually, it does assign the value, but the value isn't 1.4 or whatever, it's a reference... never mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    n = float(input("Enter a positive number: "))
    if n > 0:
        break
    print ("Error please re-input")

oldGuess = n / 2.0
while True:
    newGuess = ((n / oldGuess) + oldGuess) / 2.0;
    oldGuess = newGuess
    if -1e-6 < n - newGuess * newGuess < 1e-6:
        break

print ("Difference:", abs(n ** .5 - newGuess))
```

Comment: @user2357112, you should save the -1 for wrong answers. The SO policy on homework is quite clear. Besides there was no mention of homework when I posted this.

Comment: @gnibbler It's very obvious that it's homework, but you are correct.

Comment: so I don't know know what the breaks exactly mean. And I'm trying to follow your logic here. I still don't understand why we need an oldGuess = newGuess? can't we just do an if statement being like if newGuess - oldGuess = 1 e-6 then return nothing else: print difference?

Comment: @SulimanSharif, the `break` is to avoid needing to initialise `newGuess` before entering the loop.

Comment: @SulimanSharif: You don't *want* to return nothing. You want to keep making better and better guesses until you're close enough, then return your best guess. If you don't update `oldGuess`, you'll just keep using your first guess and keep recomputing your second guess.

Comment: did you out this line in rather than absolute function  if -1e-6 < n - newGuess * newGuess < 1e-6 ????

Answer (score 0):

Change those `eval()`s to `float()`s. `eval()` executes any code it's handed, so that means your user could type something malicious there.

Now, use this for the second part:

```
oldGuess = n / 2.0
newGuess = ((n / oldGuess) + oldGuess) / 2.0
while (abs(oldGuess - newGuess) > 1e-06):
    oldGuess, newGuess = newGuess, ((n / oldGuess) + oldGuess) / 2.0
print("Guess: " + str(n))
print("My root: " + str(newGuess))
print("Accuracy: " + str(newGuess - (n**0.5)))
```

That comma syntax is a Python idiom useful for swapping values without having to do:

```
temp = new
new = old * something
old = temp
```

Your condition for the while loop is looking to end looping when your difference is *less* than that (very small) value. So you will loop so long as it is *greater* than that.

*Note:* you can also use `math.sqrt(n)` instead of `n ** 0.5`. You'll have to `import math`.

If you want to see what your program is doing, try `print`ing the values of `oldGuess` and `newGuess` within the `while` loop. You'll see it's changing them until you've arrived at your answer.

**Edit**:

I notice that you seem to be tripped up on why you have to do `oldGuess = newGuess`. Let me explain: the `=` operator is not the same as the equals sign in mathematics. The equals sign says that the thing on the left is the same thing as the thing on the right; i.e. they are *equivalent*. In Python, the `=` operator says "give the thing on the left the same value as the thing on the right." It is called the *assignment* operator. You are thinking of the `==` operator, which tests for equivalency (basically).

```
>>> a = 10
>>> b = 4
>>> b = a
>>> b
10
>>> a == b
True
>>> c = 6
>>> b = c
>>> b
6
>>> a == b
False
>>> b == c
True
>>> a == c
False
>>> a,b,c
(10, 6, 6)
```

As you can see, when you use the `=` operator, you don't "link" the variables together, saying that they are now the same thing. If you set `b = a` and then set `b = c`, `b == a` becomes false because `b` does not have the same value as `a` anymore. `a` does not change either, because `b` was assigned its value, not the other way around. Think of the `=` operator looking like `<-` instead (I think some languages actually use this as the assignment operator).

*Why does this matter?* Well, you do assign something new to a variable, you forget the old value. Unless you have another variable storing the same value, it's lost forever. Your assignment says to update the `oldGuess` to the previous `newGuess`. In other words, if your guesses were "a", "b", "c", "d", then you'd start with `oldGuess` as "a" and from there compute `newGuess` as "b". Since this would obviously not be the correct guess, you say the `oldGuess` is now what the `newGuess` just was - "b", and you compute the next `newGuess`, which is "c".

You need the value of `oldGuess` to compute the value of `newGuess`. But, you need the value of `newGuess` (before you changed it) to update the value of `oldGuess`. It's a catch-22, unless you store the previous value of `newGuess` as I showed above (as the swapping example). That is why you need this.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. Definitely needed clarification on that

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out thanks guys for help. I didn't know we can't post homework questions on here but I am trying to definitely learn how to code so I can get better at it. Here was my final solution.

```
def main():

    n = float(input("Enter a positive number: "))
    while (n <= 0):
     print ("Error please re-input")
     n = eval(input("Enter a positive number: "))

    oldGuess = n / 2.0
    newGuess = 0

    difference = 10
    while (difference >= 1 * 10 ** -6):
     newGuess = ((n / oldGuess) + oldGuess) / 2.0
     difference = abs(newGuess - oldGuess)
     oldGuess = newGuess

    print ("Square Root is: ", newGuess)


    differenceSqrt = newGuess - n ** 0.5
    print ("Difference is: ", differenceSqrt)



main()
```

I still don't know how to use breaks effectively so thanks gnibbler but couldn't really follow your code too well. (New to this, sorry)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can ask about homework as long as your question doesn't fit into any of [these categories](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). (So make your question less specific to your assignment and more general so it will be useful for others... for example, you could title this question "trouble with loop in square root calculation" or something of that ilk.)